# node.js express dns lookup to use ipv4 always

Tags: node.js, express, dns, npm-request

Is there a way to have the express.js server always use do a dns look up for  IPV4 addresses instead of both IPv4 and IPV6 addresses?

Like we do this in a java JVM by setting the parameter java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

I am looking to do this for outgoing requests, when my add is making outbound service calls. My app uses [request npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and it uses [net npm package](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) and it uses [dns npm package](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_lookup_hostname_options_callback). The dns package has an option to set the IP family which can be 4 or 6. I think this will do what i want if i set it to 4.

Now the question is, how to pass this option from my app to be applied to this npm package at runtime.

Comment: you can specify IPv4 when you specify for server to listen on port `XXXX` just like this `app.listen(5000, '127.0.0.1');`

Comment: @SatishPatel, thanks for the response. I have updated my question above. Apologies for lack of clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this to force the DNS look up to be looking up only IPv4 addresses and not IPv6 addresses.

```
import Request from 'request';

export class SoapUtility extends Utility 
{

  constructor(options) {
        super();
        otherCode = otherCode;

        this.request = Request;
  };

  requestMainframe(args, callback) 
  {
    this.request.post({
        url: this.endpoints.userLookup,
        method: 'POST',
        family : 4,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
            "Authorization": `Basic ${creds}`
        },
        body: requestBody,
        rejectUnauthorized: false, 
    }, (error, response, body) => {
          callback(error, null);
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the [documentation from npm request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#tlsssl-protocol) and [DNS lookup details](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_lookup_hostname_options_callback)